# aframe loadin .dae dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

Good day guys

I want to cange a .dae dynamically with this in js

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-overrider', {
        init: function() {


          document.querySelector('#tree').setAttribute('src',modelo);


   }
```

and the html looks

```
   <a-assets >  
       <a-asset-item id="tree" src=" "></a-asset-item>  
    </a-assets>

      <a-entity collada-model="#tree" model-overrider></a-entity>
```

but I can´t make it work

thanks for your help,

sincerely,

Diego Ramirez.

Answer (score 2):

I believe we cannot assign a new `src` to an `a-asset-item` dynamically. Instead, we can set the `a-entity`'s `collada-model` as follows:

```
var e = document.querySelector('#myEntity');
e.setAttribute("collada-model", 'url(tree.dae)');
```